# Pronouncing the ひ sound correctly

Tags: pronunciation

I've been learning Japanese for the past month and I have a few problems pronouncing the ひ sound (being a native Hebrew speaker and fluent in English I don't believe that sound exists in those languages).

I've found that sometimes I would hear (or miss hear) the sound as a shi sound like in the sentence `いいひですね` - I would hear `iishidesune`

Could anyone give me a few pointers on how to correctly pronounce this sound?

Also does this happen only on the shi sound or does it also happen with the 
ha, ho, he sounds ?

Comment: Try extending the *H* sound of *human* or *humid*. You will find it is different from *horse* or *hat*. That is the *H* sound of ひ, ひゃ, ひゅ, and ひょ.

Comment: So it is also close to the hh sound in Hebrew? like in hanoka?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In standard Japanese, 'h' before 'i' or 'y' is pronounced a bit differently ([source](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E9%9F%B3%E9%9F%BB#.E5.AD.90.E9.9F.B3)).  In the International Phonetic Alphabet, this sound is written as [[ç]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_palatal_fricative#Palatal).  This is the sound you're hearing as kinda like a し.  However, it's still distinct from し (which is pronounced as [[ɕ]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_alveolo-palatal_sibilant)).

The ひ consonant, [ç], *does* occur in some varieties of English – e.g. British English *hue*; but, from looking at the Wikipedia article on Hebrew phonology, it looks like you guys don't have it. To understand Japanese, it's important that you get used to *hearing* the difference between these two sounds.  The Google text-to-speech system you posted will do nicely; [listen carefully](https://translate.google.com/#ja/en/%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E6%97%A5%EF%BC%9B%E3%82%A4%E3%83%BC%E6%B0%8F%E3%80%82).  Notice how ひ sounds softer and closer to English 'h', whereas し sounds noisier and closer to English 'sh'.

*Pronouncing* this sound in a Japanese way is not vitally important.  You can just use English 'he' and 'she' in your accent, and the Japanese will hear it as ひ and し.  If you want to perfect your Japanese accent, try to do this: *whisper* the vowel /i/ forcefully, then change the whisper to the voiced vowel.  (While whispering, be sure to have your tongue already in the /i/ position).

By the way, if you want to pronounce the し in a more Japanese manner, try sticking the tip of your tongue behind your *lower* front teeth.

Comment: Thank you so much! i know I wasn't just hearing things. 
I was looking for a way to make google translate sound it out for me, this does the trick.
I really do want to (in time) perfect my accent so I'l do my best with your tips.
Thanks a lot!.

Comment: What I recall from Japanese phonetics class was that pronouncing し could be helped by holding your lips taut instead of rounding them as you would to say "she."

Comment: @Casey: That sounds like a good tip – I'm not a native English speaker, and I don't round my shibilants even in my native Portuguese; I don't think the Japanese do it either. The "lower teeth" hint comes from the fact that English [ʃ] is distinct from Japanese [ɕ] mainly by "doming" the tongue tip up; roughly, [English is like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Palatoalveolar_fricative.png), [and Japanese like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Alveolopalatal_fricative.svg).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused and in standard Japanese (not in a dialect), the sound of ひ is very close to 'he' in 'Hebrew' or the personal pronoun 'he' in English.

You can watch the linked YouTube video to hear how it sounds. [Hiragana Pronunciation Practice はひふへほ (ha hi hu he ho)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOkueY7RjOs)

Comment: What you say is interesting, I might have heard a specific daialect, I also checked in google translate to check how to bot would pronounce this and it as a "hi" but when I entered the statement いいひですね I do still hear the shi sound
https://translate.google.com/#ja/en/%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E6%97%A5%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%AD

Comment: Isn't ふ closer to 'fu' in English?  At least it sounds that way to me.